# No styles in wp_admin

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Welcome,

I have a huge problem. Everything's fine on localhost. But when I upload my page to the server (site88.net), wp_admin styles don't load. The page itself is alright although.

[image: wp_admin looks like this]

I have tried what this guy wrote:

http://manovotny.com/fix-wordpress-admin-styles-not-loading/

I have also added `define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);` to wp-config.php and the result is following:

[image: Console]

Please help :)

Comment: have you checked permission of directory where you have put css ? it must be 755.

Comment: I have just checked and yes, it is 755.

Comment: Please check jquery main file have loaded or not and have you changed home_url and site_url in wp_options table?

Comment: Yes, I have just checked `if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') { alert("jQuery library is loaded!"); }else{ alert("jQuery library is not found!"); }` and I have also updated home_url and site_url in wp_options table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

1) Clear your browser cache.

2) Re-install WordPress (keep wp-content and your database, just reinstall the core files)

3) Check homeurl and siteurl form phpmyadmin

4)  rename .htaccess file form root.

5) Always user private browser remove cache issue.

That's it.

Comment: Thank you. It worked after reinstallation. That simple :D

Comment: Yes,sometime some files are missing while upload or may corrupt.Thanks for appreciation.